# получение LAPS пароля python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли какой-то способ с помощью `python` получить пароль `LAPS`. Какая-нибудь библиотека в какую сторону смотреть, подскажите где почитать можно. Так я получаю имя пользователя администратора. Как можно получить пароль?

```
import struct
import win32com.client


def get_pc(computername):
    computer = win32com.client.GetObject(f"WinNT://{computername}")
    # перебираем все его объекты (пользователи, группы)
    for obj in computer:
        # игнорируем всё, кроме пользователей
        if obj.Class != "User":
            continue
        # вычисляем админа по SID
        sid = bytes(obj.objectSid)
        if struct.unpack("i", sid[-4:])[0] == 500:
            admin = obj
            print(admin.Name)
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_pc("MY-PC")
```

или может можно как-нибудь получить результат такой команды в `powershell`

```
Get-AdmPwdPassword -ComputerName <PC-NAME>
```

из `python`

Comment: Эээ, вы полагаете, что пароли хранятся где-то в явном виде? Такого уж лет 20 мне кажется нет ни в каких системах.

Comment: @CrazyElf понятно что они не в явном виде. просто хочется сделать что-то вроде `laps ui` от `windows` . Эта утилита не очень удобна мне, хотелось бы получать пароли с телефона. Что-то вроде тг бота . Но для начало бы хотелось понять как получить пароль, как делает это данная программа

Comment: Что-то там в явном виде поля объекта нельзя посмотреть. Непонятно, как там пароль искать

Comment: @CrazyElf может есть какие-то другие способы получить пароль?